# How to get Platform Event custom field value from Save Result or Database Error in Apex

Tags: apex, platform-event, saveresult

If my `Platform Event` is configured to have a custom field `Key_Field__c`.

How do I get the value of `Key_Field__c` on the `Platform Event` object which has failed when using `EventBus.publish()`

```
void createEvents() {

    List<My_Custom_Event__e > events = new List<My_Custom_Event__e>();
    events.add(new My_Custom_Event__e(Key_Field__c = 'key field value 1'));
    events.add(new My_Custom_Event__e(Key_Field__c = 'key field value 2'));
    handleSaveResults(EventBus.publish(events));
}

void handleSaveResults(Database.SaveResult[] results) {

    for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
        if (result.isSuccess() == false) {
            for (Database.Error err : result.getErrors()) {
                String statusCode = err.getStatusCode();
                String message = err.getMessage();
                String fields = err.getFields();
                // How do I get the value of Key_Field__c ?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because I need to know which record failed, so it can be re-processed manually

**Question**

To recap: How to I get the value of a custom field on the `Platform Event`, via the `Database.SaveResult` or `Database.Error` objects?

Comment: It would seem that the publish call and the result would normally be in the same method, so you can simply reference event.Key_Field__c. Is there some circumstance where the result is in a different method?

Comment: @MikeLockett - good point, my example was too simple, IRL there are multiple records. I will update example

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I don't see a way to get the data from the error.

I believe the results come back ordered properly, in which case, something like this should work:

```
void createEvents() {

    List<My_Custom_Event__e > events = new List<My_Custom_Event__e>();
    events.add(new My_Custom_Event__e(Key_Field__c = 'key field value 1'));
    events.add(new My_Custom_Event__e(Key_Field__c = 'key field value 2'));
    publishMyEvents(events);
}

void publishMyEvents(My_Custom_Event__e events) {
    Integer i=0;
    Database.SaveResult[] results = EventBus.publish(events);

    for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
        if (result.isSuccess() == false) {
            for (Database.Error err : result.getErrors()) {
                String statusCode = err.getStatusCode();
                String message = err.getMessage();
                String fields = err.getFields();                
            }
            // How do I get the value of Key_Field__c ?
            // this shouldn't need to be in the inner loop
            events[i].Key_Field__c; 
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

It might make sense to return a String[] of failed Key Fields.